# Want to develop JasperReport with Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports

I am developing project using `Spring`, `Struts2` & `Hibernate`.

Now I want to use a `JasperReport` with `Struts2`.

But I am totally new with `JasperReport`.

Can anyone give simple example or a tutorial or any other link which can help me..

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any jasper-report tutorial will be good for you. Struts2 won't have much influence on how you generate your JasperReport.

You might want to take a look at "Stream Result":

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html

**EDIT:**
I just found this and I think this is what you are looking for:
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

We use Struts2, Spring and Hibernate in our projects. There are two ways we do Jasper Reports and they both use the Struts2-Jasper plugin

1. Use Hiberate to retrieve the List of objects to be put in the report. This technique we try avoid as much as possible as the report is not portable and forces the report to be generated in the same JVM as your application.
2. We use embedded SQL in the JRXML. This we think is a better approach because eventually we can upload the JRXML to a dedicated JasperServer. Prior to Struts 2.1.x this was difficult to implement because there is no way to pass the connection to the JRXML. The following is the tutorial as to how to integrate Jasper Report with embedded SQL with Struts 2

http://yellow-jbox.blogspot.com/2011/04/jasper-report-with-embedded-sql-using.html

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that Tahir mentions should help you out. I think I wrote the first version of that way back in the Webwork days. The way that this works is to take a property of your action as an iterable type and to use that as a Jasper data source. That way you can report on your actions instead of against the database. I wrote this to allow us to report against a Versant object database which no reporting tools existed for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jasper report in Stuts2 just use that one.This Plugin will provide all the basic infrastructure need to start develpoing Jasper reports in Struts2